# Class 'AMQPConnection' not found

Tags: amqp

I am using Mac OSX Lion. I am running php ver 5.3.6 through MAMP and when trying the create a AMQPConnection I get this error

Class 'AMQPConnection' not found

I installed rabbitmq through macports using this command

$ sudo port install rabbitmq-server

I run the server using this command

$ sudo rabbitmq-server -detached

It all works fine

I added "extension=amqp.so" to my php.ini file. More specifically my /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini file.

I have rabbitmq-c
I ran autoreconf -i && ./Configure && make && sudo make install with no errors

I configured rabbit with this command phpize && ./configure && make && make install

All that seemed to go perfectly.

I even created my user with permissions and verified those permissions with the web plugins that can be accessed through localhost:55672

I even tried copying amqp.so into my /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ file in a futile attempt to get it working.

Everything that I have done has seemed to work flawlessly. I get no error/warning messages. The Rabbit server is running. I ran it without the -detached option to see if I was getting any errors there. Nothing.

Any Suggestions??????

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test your RabbitMQ Server installation is by testing with simple python code.

Installing PIKA library on Mac OSX is very easy. Follow the steps given here.
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

copy paste and create two python files receive.py and send.py. Execute these from two terminal windows. In about 10 minutes you'll know that RabbitMQ is able to receive the message and queue.

Create the info.php on server with 
Check the results from browser if it shows AMQP library is active.

I feel your RabbitMQ server is installed, but PHP library is not getting loaded correctly.
Check your error.log. There must be some details why it is failing to load 'amqp.so' file.

Answer (score 0):

Can You please Add:

`use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;`

under your:

`use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;`

line and it will work.